# How to read data from bluetooth barcode scanner to android device using bluetooth ?

Tags: android, bluetooth

In my project i have to read  barcodes using barcode scanner through bluetooth. 
i.e; i have to establish a connection between android device and  barcode scanner through bluetooth. Can any one tell me how to read values from barcode reader and how to setup for communication  ?

Thanking you,
Srinivas

Comment: I'd say that depends on the barcode scanner - wasn't a datasheet shipped together with the scanner?

Comment: If nothing else, it would be much easier to answer your question if you supplied the name of the barcode reader in question.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use [TEC-IT's BluePiano Bluetooth Wedge](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.tecit.android.bluepiano.demo&hl=en).  This is a replacement soft keyboard that can pair with a bluetooth scanner and dump the scan into the currently focused field.

The major negative of this solution, in my opinion, is that it's necessary to replace whatever soft keyboard you're used to using with the BluePiano one.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try serialmagic gears. Can get a demo from app store

I found this to be better that Blue Piano ($50 for license)